# Ubuntu 16.04 live CD not accepting password for wifi - Ralink RT3290

Tags: wireless, password, live-usb, 16.04, live-cd

Ubuntu 16.04 live CD is not accepting wifi password for the WPA2 wifi network. Wifi is Ralink RT3290 pci express wifi card. The wifi card is working with Ubuntu 15.10 live CD.

Wifi driver rt2800pci is loaded and communicating with other modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wifi password manager is not able to store the password for all users in the keychain. Therefore when entering the password choose the people icon in the password box and choose store the password only for this user. The system will prompt you for a keychain password. Next go to network manager and choose your wifi network. The network manager should connect you this time.

In case you need to troubleshoot use following commands:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo ifconfig wlo1 up
```